# Action of the Fundamental Group of Klein Bottle over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups, group-cohomology

It is well know that the Fundamental Group of the Klein Bottle is defined by

$$G=BS(1,-1)=\langle a,b:bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle$$

An explicit description can be obtaned by define $G$ as the group of homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ generate by the functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$

$$f(x,y)=(x,y+1), g(x,y)=(x+1,1-y)$$

A linear action of $G$ over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is an aplication $"\cdot":G\times \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that:

1.- $a\cdot(x_{1}+x_{2})=a\cdot x_{1}+a\cdot x_{2}$

2.- $a\cdot (b\cdot x)=(ab)\cdot x$

3.- $1_{G}\cdot x=x$

for all $a,b\in G$ and $x,x_{1},x_{2}\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$

My question is : how to define a linear action of $G$ over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: You can embed ${\rm Aff}(2,\Bbb R)$ into ${\rm GL}(3,\Bbb R)$ if you want.

Comment: this might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799777/how-to-get-a-presentation-of-a-group/2724113#2724113

Comment: @JoseCamarillo there are [such actions on the wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group) for BS groups but it is not faithful in this case. Don't think there are faithful ones but I would have to think of a full argument (there is a restriction of abelian subgroups and this group is virtually abelian)

Comment: Also if you are going to include homological tags you should probably mention why in your question

Comment: @runway44 how is this embedding?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group#Matrix_representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group#Matrix_representation)